# WPF ContentControl : how to change control opacity in disabled mode in .cs file?

Tags: c#-3.0, wpf-controls

I have `public class MyControl : ContentControl` in wchich i have definitions of control and events corresponding with it.

This control works fine, but when is disabled it looks still like enabled. I would like to do something like if `control.isenabled = false` then `control.opacity = 0.5;` How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said - this trigger don't work - I have checked...

But I have found solution - in OnApplyTemplate method I have added few lines:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    //...
    if (this.IsEnabled == false)
    {
        this.Opacity = 0.4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In WPF for such things triggers are used.

```
<MyControl>
<MyControl.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
       <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
   </Trigger>
</MyControl.Triggers>
</MyControl>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i would like to make those changes in .cs file not in xaml. Can i set those triggers somehow in .cs file where i have definition of my coontrol?

Comment: Sure you can, but you shouldn't - it will be too complicated. Handle IsEnabledChanged event to change control opacity

Comment: You actually can't use a Trigger like this. Property Triggers are only allowed in Style or Template Triggers collections. In this context only an EventTrigger would be valid. That said, Yurec is correct that it is much preferred in WPF to do this in the ControlTemplate XAML for your control than in code.